# Scraping multiple page on this site HELP NEEDED

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Hi I would love to be able to scrape multiple page for this website
Can some one give help on how i can scrape scrape through all the pages i am only able to get information from one page how ever I just get information from one page

```
    headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})

for i in range(2000):
  Centris ='https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent~montreal-ville-marie/26349148?view=Summary'.format(i)

r = get(Centris, headers=headers)

soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'divMainResult'})

data = []
for result in results:
  
  titre = result.find('span', attrs={'data-id': 'PageTitle'})
  titre = [str(titre.string).strip() for titre in titre]

  superficie = result.find('div', attrs={'class': 'carac-value'}, string=re.compile('sqft'))
  superficie = [str(superficie.string).strip() for superficie in superficie]

  emplacement = result.find_all('h2', attrs={'class': 'pt-1'})
  emplacement = [str(emplacement.string).strip() for emplacement in emplacement]
 
 
  prix =  result.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'text-nowrap'})
  prix = [(prix.text).strip('\w.') for prix in prix]
  
  
  
  description = result.find_all('div', attrs={'itemprop': 'description'})
  description = [str(description.string).strip() for description in description]
  
  
  lien = result.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'dropdown-item js-copy-clipboard'})
```

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to get info from? `https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent~montreal-ville-marie/26349148?view=Summary` is only one property

Comment: Hi thank for your quick response, Basicly i need the information on this page but all all other properties. https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent~ ,

Comment: Clicking on this URL gives me 404 error page

Comment: My mistake, https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent?uc=0

Answer (score 1):

To get pagination working you can simulate Ajax requests with `requests` module:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetInscriptions"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
}
json_data = {"startPosition": 0}

with requests.session() as s:

    # load cookies:
    s.get(
        "https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent?uc=0",
        headers=headers,
    )
    for page in range(0, 100, 20):  # <-- increase number of pages here
        json_data["startPosition"] = page

        data = s.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data).json()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data["d"]["Result"]["html"], "html.parser")

        for a in soup.select(".a-more-detail"):
            print(a.select_one(".category").get_text(strip=True))
            print(a.select_one(".address").get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
            print("https://www.centris.ca" + a["href"])
            print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Commercial unit for rent
6560, Avenue de l'Esplanade, suite 105
Montréal (Rosemont/La Petite-Patrie)
Neighbourhood La Petite-Patrie
https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent~montreal-rosemont-la-petite-patrie/16168393?view=Summary
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Commercial unit for rent
75, Rue  Principale
Gatineau (Aylmer)
Neighbourhood Vieux Aylmer, Des Cèdres, Marina
https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent~gatineau-aylmer/22414903?view=Summary
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Commercial building for rent
53, Rue  Saint-Pierre, suite D
Saint-Pie
https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-buildings~for-rent~saint-pie/15771470?view=Summary
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Hi, I have try this however when putting this in a excel I get a max of 19 result even tho i added more pages


for page in range(128):  # <-- increase number of pages here
        json_data["startPosition"] = page

        data = s.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data).json()
        soup = bs(data["d"]["Result"]["html"], "html.parser")

        data = []

Comment: @CatsTv Put the results in a list and after the `with` statement create a dataframe from this list. After that,  save it as excel file. The range needst to be `range(0, 1000, 20)` for example

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much I came up with this and it worked perfectly

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetInscriptions"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
}
json_data = {"startPosition": 0}

with requests.session() as s:
    Centris = []
    # load cookies:
    s.get(
        "https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent?uc=0",
        headers=headers,
    )
    for page in range(0, 100, 20):  # <-- increase number of pages here
        json_data["startPosition"] = page

        data = s.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data).json()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data["d"]["Result"]["html"], "html.parser")

        for a in soup.select(".a-more-detail"):
            titre = a.select_one(".category").get_text(strip=True)
            emplacement = a.select_one(".address").get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")
            lien = "https://www.centris.ca" + a["href"]
            prix = a.select_one(".price").get_text(strip=True)
            

            Centris.append((titre, emplacement, lien, prix))


df = pd.DataFrame(Centris, columns={'Titre':titre, 'Emplacement':emplacement, 'Lien':lien, 'Prix':prix})


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Centris.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer)

writer.save()
print( 'Data Saved To excel' )
```